# Newton method of nonlinear system

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

This is the newton method for nonlinear system, 
$$x_1 = x_0 − (Df(x_0))^{-1} f(x_0)$$
why in practice we never use the inverse of a matrix for computations, so we cannot use this formula directly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Nonlinear_systems_of_equations

Comment: The two forms $Df(x_1-x_0) = -f$ and $x_1 = x_0 - Df^{-1} f$ are equivalent ways of writing the system. You can use both, but in practice the former is often better because 1) it's more efficient to solve the former system (less operations) 2) finding the inverse of a matrix can be numerically unstable in some cases.